# How to disable LWUIT's transition effects?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40

I'm developing an app for Nokia Asha 501 using LWUIT 1.5 and I'm trying to disable the fade effect that happens when transitioning from one form to another by using the CategoryBay component.

I've looked around the web but only mentions of how to use transitions come as results.

Is there a way to completely disable these transition effects to save up memory resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a similar project.

First have you considered using LWUIT Tabs over CategoryBar? It doesn't have any animation AFAIK and is quite customizable.

Second for CategoryBar,

Have you tried:

```
cat.setTransitionSupport(false)?
```

Fenix

Comment: Also I would say for Asha 501 you shouldn't have to worry about memory, but of course i'm guessing you want to backwards support older devices.

Comment: Thanks that was the method I was looking for, for some reason in Nokia's LWUIT documentation the category bar is not featured so I was at a loss there. 

The problem I noticed with Asha 501 is that the more you use the device by opening different apps, the slower it gets and I've been optimizing my code and been using png only where it is required but stuff like transitions were making it slower.

Comment: No problem. It's not in Nokia's LWUIT javadoc because it's not a part of LWUIT, but of Nokia's mid classes. I had the same misunderstanding because their developer site put CategoryBar under LWUIT. Also thanks for the Asha tip

Comment: PNG are poisonous if your app uses many graphic resources, better to stick to JPG if you don't need transparency.